# How to get a variable to work in an HTML file from google forms?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using a google script attached to my google form to send emails of the results. When I have it sending via regular text, the variables work. But when I try to use it via an HTML file the variables are showing up as the variable name.

I got it working via Text but not HTML

The .gs file is:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {

  var JobName = e.values[10];
    var JobDate = e.values[1];
    var SubmitterName = e.values[2];

    var subject = "Job Form Submitted";
  var htmlBody = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('emailtext').getContent();


  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: xxx@xxxx.com
    subject: 'Test Email markup - ',
    htmlBody: htmlBody,
  });
}
```

The HTML file is:

```
</head>

<body>

<p><strong>Submitter Name: </strong>%SubmitterName</p>
<p><strong>Job Name:</strong> %JobName</p>
</body>
```

The variables should display not the variable name

Answer (score 1):

- You want to use `%SubmitterName` of `<p><strong>Submitter Name: </strong>%SubmitterName</p>` as the variable of `var SubmitterName = e.values[2]`.
- You want to use `%JobName` of `<p><strong>Job Name:</strong> %JobName</p>` as the variable of `var JobName = "e.values[10]`.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, Google Apps Script is modified as follows. The values are replaced by `replace()`.

#### From:

```
var htmlBody = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('emailtext').getContent();
```

#### To:

```
var htmlBody = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('emailtext').getContent();
htmlBody = htmlBody.replace("%SubmitterName", SubmitterName);
htmlBody = htmlBody.replace("%JobName", JobName);
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, both Google Apps Script and HTML are modified as follows. The values are replaced using the Templated HTML.

#### Google Apps Script:

From:

```
var htmlBody = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('emailtext').getContent();
```

To:

```
var htmlBody = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('emailtext');
htmlBody.obj = {JobName: JobName, JobDate: JobDate, SubmitterName: SubmitterName};
htmlBody = htmlBody.evaluate().getContent();
```

#### HTML

From:

```
<p><strong>Submitter Name: </strong>%SubmitterName</p>
<p><strong>Job Name:</strong> %JobName</p>
```

To:

```
<p><strong>Submitter Name: </strong><?= obj.SubmitterName ?></p>
<p><strong>Job Name:</strong><?= obj.JobName ?></p>
```

#### Note:

- Please select one from above 2 patterns.

#### References:

- [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)
- [HTML Service: Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.